# Interpretation of effect of factor-by-smooths in GAM

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

Given the following data and model, we'd like to assess if `treatment` affects the effect of `conc` on `uptake`.

```
library(gratia)
library(tidyverse)
library(mgcv)

# Data
data(CO2, package = "datasets")
plant <- CO2 |>
  as_tibble() |>
  rename(plant = Plant, type = Type, treatment = Treatment) |>
  mutate(plant = factor(plant, ordered = FALSE),
         uptake = ifelse(treatment == "chilled" & type == "Quebec", uptake+10, uptake))

# GAM
m_plant <- gam(uptake ~ treatment * type + 
                 s(conc, by = treatment, k = 6) +
                 s(plant, bs = "re"),
               data = plant, 
               method = "REML", 
               familly = Gamma(link = "log"))

# Fitted values
ds <- data_slice(m_plant, 
                 treatment = levels(treatment),
                 type = levels(type),
                 conc = evenly(conc, n = 100))

fitted <-  fitted_values(m_plant, 
                         data = ds, 
                         scale = "response",
                         exclude = "s(plant)")

# Smooth estimates
se <- smooth_estimates(m_plant, "s(conc)", 
                       partial_match = TRUE)
```

[image]

By predicting uptake, we can see that at given `conc`, `uptake` is higher for `chilled` plants for `type = Mississippi` and higher for `nonchilled` plants for `type = Quebec`. Can we still draw a general conclusion concerning the effect of `treatment` on the effect of `conc` on `uptake`, regardless of `type`, based on the smooth estimates? For instance, the plot of the smooth estimates shows that at e.g. `conc = 500`, the effect on `uptake` is stronger for `nonchilled` plants. Does such difference in intercept/position along the y-axis have any meaning when considering the global smooth effect? Alternatively, is it possible to compare the smooth effect for the types seperately (other than predicting values)?

*Edit:*

I think my question is related to [this issue/discussion on github](https://github.com/gavinsimpson/gratia/issues/108). Maybe I am just looking for something like `smooth_estimates(..., group_means = TRUE`). I tried to calculate that based on the difference smooth..

```
# Difference smooth with group means
ds_gm <- difference_smooths(m_plant, select = "s(conc)", 
                            partial_match = TRUE, 
                            group_means = TRUE) %>%
  select(.diff, conc)

# Filter smooth estimate for nonchilled
se2 <- se %>%
  add_confint() %>%
  filter(treatment == "nonchilled") %>%
  select(.estimate, conc)

# Calculate smooth estimate for chilled from difference
left_join(ds_gm, se2) %>%
  mutate(.estimate_chilled = .estimate - .diff) %>%
  ggplot(.) +
  geom_line(aes(x = conc, y = .estimate)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = conc, y = .estimate_chilled), colour = "red")
```

[image]

Would this allow to conclude that the effect of `conc` on `uptake` is always stronger for `chilled` than `nonchilled` plants (confidence intervals left aside)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are interested in the statistical estimation of differences between the two smooths formed by the `s(conc, by = treatment, k = 6)` term. If this is what you are interested in, your can compute differences between (pairs of) smooths using `gratia::difference_smooths()` but you can also do this yourself as it is based on a particular set of contrasts forming a specific linear combination of the model coefficients.

```r
library("gratia")
library("mgcv")
library("tibble")
library("dplyr")

data(CO2, package = "datasets")
plant <- CO2 |>
  as_tibble() |>
  rename(plant = Plant, type = Type, treatment = Treatment) |>
  mutate(plant = factor(plant, ordered = FALSE),
         uptake = ifelse(treatment == "chilled" & type == "Quebec", uptake+10, uptake))

# GAM
m_plant <- gam(uptake ~ treatment * type + 
                 s(conc, by = treatment, k = 6) +
                 s(plant, bs = "re"),
               data = plant, 
               method = "REML", 
               family = Gamma(link = "log"))

diffs <- difference_smooths(m_plant, select = "s(conc)")
```

With the dev version of {gratia} on GitHub this produces

```
> diffs                                                                       
# A tibble: 100 × 9
   .smooth .by       .level_1  .level_2   .diff    .se .lower_ci .upper_ci  conc
   <chr>   <chr>     <chr>     <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 s(conc) treatment nonchill… chilled  -0.262  0.0353    -0.331 -0.193      95 
 2 s(conc) treatment nonchill… chilled  -0.236  0.0310    -0.297 -0.175     104.
 3 s(conc) treatment nonchill… chilled  -0.211  0.0273    -0.264 -0.157     113.
 4 s(conc) treatment nonchill… chilled  -0.185  0.0246    -0.233 -0.137     122.
 5 s(conc) treatment nonchill… chilled  -0.161  0.0229    -0.205 -0.116     132.
 6 s(conc) treatment nonchill… chilled  -0.136  0.0223    -0.180 -0.0927    141.
 7 s(conc) treatment nonchill… chilled  -0.113  0.0227    -0.158 -0.0688    150.
 8 s(conc) treatment nonchill… chilled  -0.0911 0.0237    -0.137 -0.0447    159.
 9 s(conc) treatment nonchill… chilled  -0.0700 0.0248    -0.119 -0.0213    168.
10 s(conc) treatment nonchill… chilled  -0.0503 0.0259    -0.101  0.000551  177.
# ℹ 90 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

(The CRAN version will produce something similar but the `select` argument is named something else and the variables in the returned object have different names.)

We can visualise this with the `draw()` method

```r
diffs |> draw()
```

[image]

How do we interpret this? We can see what's happening via a few steps (that `difference_smooths()` doesn't actually do directly. First we create some values of `conc` and `treatment` to compute predicted values for:

```r
ds <- data_slice(m_plant, conc = evenly(conc),
  treatment = evenly(treatment))
```

Note this also creates values for `plant` and `type` (constant) but we'll remove those effects from the fitted values in the next step, using `terms` to choose just the effects of the two smooths created by the factor by smooth:

```r
fv <- fitted_values(m_plant, data = ds, scale = "link",
  terms = smooths(m_plant)[1:2])
```

Note we are doing this on the link (log) scale as that is what is shown on the plot you were discussing.

Now we can compute a difference using some dplyr foo (but we don't get any uncertainty estimates doing it this waY)

```r
fv |> 
    group_by(conc) |> 
    summarise(.diff = -diff(.fitted))
```

This produces

```
# A tibble: 100 × 2
    conc   .diff
   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1   95  -0.262 
 2  104. -0.236 
 3  113. -0.211 
 4  122. -0.185 
 5  132. -0.161 
 6  141. -0.136 
 7  150. -0.113 
 8  159. -0.0911
 9  168. -0.0700
10  177. -0.0503
# ℹ 90 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

From this we see that `chilled` starts off having higher `uptake` than `nonchilled`, but that difference decreases quickly up to `conc` ~ 200, after which `nonchilled` leads to larger `uptake` values than `chilled` up to about `conc` 600, after which the difference decreases towards 0. Given this, we see that the effect of `conc` on `uptake` changes more rapidly as we increase `conc` up to about `conc = 300`, and after that we see similar changes in `uptake` as we increase `conc` in the two levels of the treatment, with `nonchilled` leading to larger `uptake` at a given `conc`. All of this is really in terms of $\log(\text{uptake})$ of course.

What we just looked at is the difference in the effects of `conc` on `uptake` between `treatments` **excluding** the treatment mean effects. So we are focusing on how the effect on `uptake` varies with `conc` alone, regardless of the constant offset between the two treatment levels. In other words we focus on differences in the *shape* of the smooth effects on the log scale.

If you're interested in the group means being included in the comparison, you can do that with `group_means = TRUE`:

```r
difference_smooths(m_plant, select = "s(conc)", group_means = TRUE)
```

> Does such difference in intercept/position along the y-axis have any meaning when considering the global smooth effect?

Yes, it is the magnitude of the effect of `conc` on the response *centred* on the model constant term (so centred about the mean for `treatment == "nonchilled" & type == "Quebec"`)

However, your language suggests that you shouldn't be doing any of this on the log scale. The way you describe the problem it seems like you are interested in the actual response of `uptake` as a function of `conc` for the two `treatment` levels. In which case you should be using the response scale for this, excluding the effects of model terms you are not interested in:

```r
fv2 <- fitted_values(m_plant, data = ds,
  terms = c("treatmentchilled", smooths(m_plant)[1:2]))

fv2 |>
  ggplot(aes(x = conc, y = .fitted, group = treatment)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = .lower_ci, ymax = .upper_ci, fill = treatment),
    alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = treatment))
```

[image]

This plot is showing the estimated effects of `conc` on `uptake` **plus** the difference between `chilled` and `nonchilled` levels. We've excluded the `type` effects here, but we are missing the average `uptake` to scale the y axis in terms of observed `uptake` values.

If you want a difference on this response scale, then the easiest way to get it is to use {marginaleffects} as Nick showed. Use `comparisons()` instead of `avg_comparisons()` if you want actual comparisons for specified data values, and you'll need to figure out what `datagrid` to use if you want evenly-spaced values over `conc` for plotting.

But I actually think you should be comparing treatment effects within `type`, as what does the average across `type`s mean?

You can approach this with {gratia} using `fitted_samples()` to do posterior sampling, and then difference the fitted values for the comparisons of interests for each posterior draw. ({gratia} doesn't do the delta method to get confidence intervals on the response scale for `difference_smooths`-like operations. Instead we can do it with brute force via posterior sampling.)

First, set up the data we want to generate fitted values for

```r
ds <- data_slice(m_plant, conc = evenly(conc), type = evenly(type),
  treatment = evenly(treatment)) |>
  mutate(.row = row_number())
```

Now we take a large set of posterior draws

```r
fs <- fitted_samples(m_plant, data = ds, n = 50000, seed = 42)
```

add on the variables from `ds`

```r
fs <- fs |> left_join(ds, by = join_by(.row == .row))
```

Now we compute differences between the two treatment levels and summarise the posterior distribution of those differences with the 0.25, 0.5, and 0.975 probability quantiles

```r
library("tidyr")

quantile_fun <- function(x, probs = c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975), ...) {
  tibble::tibble(
    .value = quantile(x, probs = probs, ...),
    .q = probs * 100
  )
}

diffs <- fs |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("type", "conc", ".draw"),
    names_from = "treatment", values_from = ".fitted") |>
  mutate(.diff = nonchilled - chilled) |>
  group_by(type, conc) |>
  reframe(quantile_fun(.diff)) |>
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(type, conc), names_from = .q, values_from = .value,
    names_prefix = ".q"
  )
```

Finally we plot:

```r
diffs |>
  ggplot(aes(x = conc, y = .q50, group = type)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = .q2.5, ymax = .q97.5, fill = type), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = type)) +
  labs(y = "Estimated difference",
    title = "Difference between treatment levels",
    subtitle = "Comparison: nonchilled - chilled")
```

yielding

[image]

which matches what is shown in your faceted fitted values plots in the original post (just differencing the two curves per facet).

What I think this illustrates is that we have to be very clear about what we want to compare when working with GAMs, especially when we are working with non-identity link functions. Are we interested in differences of shape only? Differences among which factor levels? On the response scale or the link scale?

To close, how does my brute force method compare with the elegance of `marginaleffects::comparisons()`?

```r
meff <- comparisons(m_plant, newdata = ds, variables = "treatment",
  by = c("conc", "type"))

meff |> # note I'm negating the values because the comparison is opposite mine
  ggplot(aes(x = conc, y = -estimate, group = type)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = -conf.low, ymax = -conf.high, fill = type),
    alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = type))
```

[image]

Which is pretty similar to the one I produced via brute force sampling, and that's reassuring.

Hopefully this gives you examples of the different ways you can compare your smooths in the GAM, and among those is the answer you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful and I think I am slowly getting convinced that I have to work with fitted values for my purpose. Yet, something like `smooth_estimates(..., group_means = TRUE)`, would that actually be useful at all (to be able to compare the effect of `treatment` at the scale of the effect of `conc`)?

Comment: Adding group means would actually require some careful rethinking because of how it would interact with `overall_uncertainty`, and besides, these are partial effect plots and meant for comparison of the estimated smooth functions, not linear combinations of the model terms. With `fitted-values()` or the marginaleffects package you can achieve what you want (by specifying the `terms` or `exclude` arguments (only one of) to choose which terms to include or exclude respectively from the model predictions. Just ask for things on the link scale.

Answer (score 7):

As you can see from Gavin's reply, this can be done with your {`gratia`} outputs. Hwer I briefly show how you can tackle this question with {`marginaleffects`}. I first compute the average (marginal) contrast for the two levels of `treatment` on the link scale (aggregated across values of `conc`). I then show how you can do this for a sequence of `conc` values to effectively ask whether one treatment consistently gives larger linear predictor values than another. Hopefully that gets at what your're interested in, but if not there are many other types of comparisons you can make, including specific hypothesis tests. See [the {'marginaleffects'} hypothesis vignette for details](https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/hypothesis.html).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(mgcv)
library(marginaleffects)
library(ggplot2)

# Data
data(CO2, package = "datasets")
plant <- CO2 |>
  as_tibble() |>
  rename(plant = Plant, type = Type, treatment = Treatment) |>
  mutate(plant = factor(plant, ordered = FALSE),
         uptake = ifelse(treatment == "chilled" & type == "Quebec", 
                         uptake+10, uptake))

# GAM
m_plant <- gam(uptake ~ treatment * type + 
                 s(conc, by = treatment, k = 6) +
                 s(plant, bs = "re"),
               data = plant, 
               method = "REML", 
               family = Gamma(link = "log"))

# Conditional smooths on the link scale (these are what we want to difference)
plot_predictions(m_plant, 
                 condition = c('conc', 'treatment', 
                               'type'),
                 type = 'link') +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```r
# Average difference (again on the link scale) between
# treatments (aggregating over 'type' and 'conc' values)
avg_comparisons(m_plant, 
                variables = "treatment",
                by = "type", type = 'link')
#> 
#>       Term                         Contrast        type Estimate Std. Error
#>  treatment mean(chilled) - mean(nonchilled) Quebec         0.186     0.0939
#>  treatment mean(chilled) - mean(nonchilled) Mississippi   -0.477     0.0939
#>      z Pr(>|z|)    S    2.5 % 97.5 %
#>   1.98   0.0479  4.4  0.00168  0.370
#>  -5.07   <0.001 21.3 -0.66071 -0.292
#> 
#> Columns: term, contrast, type, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, predicted_lo, predicted_hi, predicted 
#> Type:  link

# Our estimand of interest: average differencea (again on the link scale) between
# treatments, aggregated over 'type' values for a sequence 
# of 'conc' values
avg_comparisons(m_plant, 
                variables = "treatment",
                by = c("conc", "type"),
                type = 'link')
#> 
#>       Term                         Contrast conc        type Estimate
#>  treatment mean(chilled) - mean(nonchilled)   95 Quebec         0.448
#>  treatment mean(chilled) - mean(nonchilled)   95 Mississippi   -0.215
#>  treatment mean(chilled) - mean(nonchilled)  175 Quebec         0.241
#>  treatment mean(chilled) - mean(nonchilled)  175 Mississippi   -0.422
#>  treatment mean(chilled) - mean(nonchilled)  250 Quebec         0.131
#>  treatment mean(chilled) - mean(nonchilled)  250 Mississippi   -0.532
#>  treatment mean(chilled) - mean(nonchilled)  350 Quebec         0.102
#>  treatment mean(chilled) - mean(nonchilled)  350 Mississippi   -0.560
#>  treatment mean(chilled) - mean(nonchilled)  500 Quebec         0.101
#>  treatment mean(chilled) - mean(nonchilled)  500 Mississippi   -0.562
#>  treatment mean(chilled) - mean(nonchilled)  675 Quebec         0.134
#>  treatment mean(chilled) - mean(nonchilled)  675 Mississippi   -0.529
#>  treatment mean(chilled) - mean(nonchilled) 1000 Quebec         0.145
#>  treatment mean(chilled) - mean(nonchilled) 1000 Mississippi   -0.517
#>  Std. Error     z Pr(>|z|)    S   2.5 % 97.5 %
#>      0.1004  4.46   <0.001 16.9  0.2509  0.644
#>      0.1004 -2.14   0.0324  4.9 -0.4115 -0.018
#>      0.0974  2.47   0.0134  6.2  0.0500  0.432
#>      0.0974 -4.33   <0.001 16.0 -0.6124 -0.231
#>      0.0971  1.35   0.1785  2.5 -0.0597  0.321
#>      0.0971 -5.47   <0.001 24.4 -0.7221 -0.341
#>      0.0996  1.02   0.3062  1.7 -0.0933  0.297
#>      0.0996 -5.62   <0.001 25.7 -0.7557 -0.365
#>      0.1005  1.00   0.3169  1.7 -0.0964  0.297
#>      0.1005 -5.59   <0.001 25.4 -0.7588 -0.365
#>      0.1007  1.33   0.1847  2.4 -0.0638  0.331
#>      0.1007 -5.25   <0.001 22.7 -0.7262 -0.331
#>      0.1008  1.44   0.1492  2.7 -0.0522  0.343
#>      0.1008 -5.13   <0.001 21.7 -0.7146 -0.319
#> 
#> Columns: term, contrast, conc, type, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, predicted_lo, predicted_hi, predicted 
#> Type:  link

# Plot these differences and add some labels
plot_comparisons(m_plant, 
                 variables = "treatment",
                 by = c("conc", "type"),
                 type = 'link') +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 'dashed') +
  labs(y = "Estimated difference",
       title = "Difference between treatment levels",
       subtitle = "Chilled - nonchilled, per type") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-22 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that does not answer my question. I am looking for how to interpret the global smooth effect of treatment (unconditional of type) OR comparing the smooth per type (but with the partial effect on the y-axis, not based on fitted values of uptake).

Comment: What I provided gives you the average (global) effect of `treatment`, irrespective of `type`. But if you want to make comparisons per level of `type`, and you want this on the partial effect (i.e. `link`) scale, use the `by` argument: ```avg_comparisons(m_plant, variables = "treatment", by = "type", type = 'link')```. I didn't originally catch the typo in your original call to the family, where you use: ```familly = Gamma(link = "log")```. This is being ignored so you are actually getting a Gaussian model with ```link = 'identity'```. Fixing this will produce more meaningful comparisons.

Comment: Thanks! Still not sure if we are talking about the same aim though. I added some thoughts to my question, maybe that clarifies what I intend to do.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I get it now. I've edited my response to show how you can target these questions (differences among smooths, with uncertainties accounted for). Hope that clarifies, but if not I'd suggest you read over the immense doc for the {`marginaleffects`}

Comment: Thanks for all your effort, I'll definitely look into the marginaleffects package.

Comment: A pleasure. I've edited my answer to show how you can plot what you're interested in. Also used this as motivation for a quick blog post on how to interpret GAMs with {marginal effects}: https://ecogambler.netlify.app/blog/interpreting-gams/. Hope it can be useful